# data.table steps inside evalparse is not recognizing data.table style syntax

Tags: r, data.table

I have a package with a function where I provide data, and wrangling steps as text in a list (alg).

```
gen_counts<-function(alg){
  gen_data<-function(...){
    suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(RODBC))
    suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(data.table))
    dbhandle<-odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server}; server=vmdata.int; trusted_connection=T; DBMSencoding ='UTF-8'")
    on.exit(odbcCloseAll())
    data.table(sqlQuery(dbhandle,text_query1,stringsAsFactor=FALSE, as.is=TRUE))
  }
  textquery1<="select * from dbo.dispenseTable"

  data<-gen_data(text_query1=text_query1)

  eval(parse(text=alg$a2))

  eval(parse(text=alg$a3))
}
```

Here I provide some basic calculations in a1, and a2. For example a1 looks like this.

```
alg$a1[length(alg$a2)+1]<-as.character('
                                       library(data.table);
                                       data[, medcount:=length(unique(tolower(DrugIngredient))), by=PatientID];
                                       ')
```

I get this error when I try this:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'DrugIngredient' not found"

The data got a column DrugIngredient. When I run this steps (without evalparse) the steps are running fine. But within evelprse this is throwing this error. Any help?

```
sessionInfo() 
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16) 
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) 
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
 [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
 [1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices  utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] RODBC_1.3-12  cpsa.testusingR_0.0.1 data.table_1.9.7  doParallel_1.0.10    iterators_1.0.8       foreach_1.4.3         roxygen2_4.1.1.9000  
 [8] devtools_1.9.1       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.11.5  codetools_0.2-11 digest_0.6.8     chron_2.3-47     magrittr_1.5   tools_3.2.0      stringr_0.6.2    compiler_3.2.0   memoise_0.2.1
```

Here is the actual function. Instead of providing data wrangling steps inside function, I would like to pass them as arguments.

```
gen_counts_by_year<-function(startdate="2013/1/01", alg, aclass="opi", sql=NA, ...){ #First place

  # Generate quarters list (last N quarters)
  qy<-seq(as.Date(startdate), as.Date("2014-12-21"), by="quarter")
  qy<-data.frame(Q=quarter(qy), Y=year(qy))
  #qy<-qy[-nrow(qy),] # Removed the latest quarter

  suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(foreach))
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(doParallel))
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("testusingR"))

  # Make 6 cores
  if(nrow(qy)>=6){
    cl <- makeCluster(6)
  }else{
    cl <- makeCluster(nrow(qy))
  }
  registerDoParallel(cl)

  #Generate Result 
  result<-foreach (i=1:nrow(qy), .packages=c("RODBC", "data.table", "testusingR", "scales")) %dopar% {
    data<-gen_data(year=qy$Y[i], quarter=qy$Q[i], ...)

    eval(parse(text=alg$a2))

    Provider<-c("Patient","Prescriber") 

    # Create counts for table 2   
    nupc<-list()
    for(ab in seq_along(alg$a1)){
      eval(parse(text=alg$a1[[ab]])) #2nd place


      thresha<-c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
      nums<-list()
      pct <-list()

      for(thresh in seq_along(thresha)){
        dat<-data[d_ome>=thresha[thresh],]
        nums[length(nums)+1]<-list(form_num(nrow(unique(dat))))
        pct[length(pct)+1]<-list( form_num(nrow(unique(dat))*100/nrow(unique(data)), deci=TRUE) )
      }

      thresha<-paste("\u2265", thresha, " Prescribers")
      nupc[length(nupc)+1]<-list(data.frame(do.call("cbind", list(thresha, nums, pct))))
      names(nupc)[length(nupc)]<-Provider[ab]

    }
    nupc
  }

  stopCluster(cl)
  closeAllConnections()
  return(result)
}
```

Comment: Is `data` properly defined in the scope where `eval` is called?

Comment: Yeah, I have simplified the function to post the question here. But I generate the data inside function.

Comment: Please don’t post simplified code, post the  **exact** and complete (but minimal) code that exhibits the error. There’s no way we can guess what’s going on here otherwise.

Comment: So, you eval/parse R code containing data.table syntax in a parallel loop. I would be surprised if such a nightmare worked out of the box.

Comment: @Roland, yeah I do (you got it correctly) and it worked. Only steps that where I specify syntax like `data[, medcount:=length(unique(tolower(DrugIngredient))), by=PatientID]` throws an error saying object `DrugIngredient` is not found. I need to do this kind of calculations on multiple yearly data and parallel loop seemed like the right idea. I think I could just include the steps manually inside function instead of evalparse. Is there a better way to specify data.table steps to pass to a function?

Comment: [Fortune 106](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fortunes/vignettes/fortunes.pdf): "If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question."